# OAuth 2 Access Token

Tags: java

I am getting following exception while trying to read from a URL https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tokens/OAuth/2

IOException : Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tokens/OAuth/2

Can you please help ?

-Abhinav

Comment: More info would help. Does this mean anything `The request contains 1 tokens separated by \u0027=\u0027 instead of a single key value pair` to you?

Comment: Is your URL properly encoded? Give some kind of code?

Comment: you can check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsofttranslator/thread/cbb136e4-d67a-4902-acc0-986606c9c726/

Answer (score 0):

If you got following message

> The request contains 1 tokens separated by \u0027=\u0027 instead of a single key value pair

problem may be in your URL - you should pass all params in POST **body**, but URL itself must be clean - this is done for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

You might see this error message if you include a trailing ampersand ('&') on the parameters string in your POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, check that your POST is of type `x-www-form-urlencoded`, with parameters only in the POST body. `form-data` didn't work for me as well.
You can try with curl:

```
curl -X POST https://YOURURL/token -d grant_type=authorization_code -d redirect_uri=https://example-app.com/redirect -d client_id=YOURID -d client_secret=YOURSECRET -d code_verifier=YOURVERIFIER -d code=YOURCODE
```